# 32bit or 64bit Android SDK on Windows 64bit OS?

Tags: android, windows, sdk

Installing a dev machine for Android development. 64bit Win7, soon will upgrade to Win8, 16GB RAM. Now the selection at the android download:

```
64bit or 32bit Android SDK?
```

What should Duffman do? Seems most poeple here go for the 64bit version, but are there arguments for/against? Hasslefree installation?

EDIT

This question was posted because I wanted to setup JetBrains IntelliJ together with the SDK. Reason was that I did not like Eclipse in the past. So when I reached the 32/64 question while downloading I was not sure and did research. The result was that there were many troubles dependent on the 32/64bit-version. In the end I gave the current Eclipse/ADT version a try and got it running quickly. I got great support from a Jetbrains guy, but finally did not follow that route, since the Eclipse toolset just worked.

EDIT 29.7.2013

**64bit Version Eclipse works just fine**

Comment: Who is Duffman?

Comment: If you have a 64bit system, then why wouldn't you want the 64bit version?

Comment: @Ahmad: Because of hasslefree installation. This is a purely pragmatic question. Often 1 or the other version of a program is prefered for reasons one knows only after having tried it. Also, I do not expect dev tools to consume > 2GB of RAM.  Duffman is a Simpson character: http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/Duffman

Comment: thx gyozo, yesterday i posted the same comment on another question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188283/upgrading-to-0-9-from-0-8-3-1-when-using-webessentials-2-7/17188311#17188311). this question here was already at -2 since quasiclever folk voted it down. funnily enough i received a "notable question" badge for it at the same time, since >2500 viewed it. community police here is sometimes not constructive.

Comment: why is this not a real question?

Comment: It's the nature of the internet. Every community starts out as super friendly, eventually the 7334 folk who have been on for a while start getting bossy and get their panties in a twist over the smallest things until eventually the community resembles a bboard from the 90s. But dont worry - soon the next stack overflow will come out.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should install using the ADT Bundle (there is a 64 bit version).  This is super simplified, and is new with the ADT 21 release.

Find it here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Everything you need is included in the bundle, which makes things very easy.

Bottom line, use 64 bit, and use the ADT Bundle, and this should be hassle free and will result in a standard installation.

Comment: Thanks! I was dithering about on whether to use intellij/32 bit sdk or just go with the 64 bit sdk with the bundled eclipse.

Comment: Very useful, as a not frequent android deveolper, i was looking for and digging for a 64 bits SDK, on forums, etc. Thanks!