# Upgrading to 0.9 from 0.8.3.1 when using WebEssentials 2.7

Tags: typescript

I have WebEssentials 2.7 and TypeScript 0.8.3.1 both installed in VS2012.
May I upgrade to 0.9 or with other words does WebEssentials 2.7 support TypeScript 0.9?
Thanks for all aswers
netdidi

Comment: I came to so to get an answer to this question and am happy to find it, together with BASarat's confirmation it works for him. Find it harsh to downote the question. As often, questions closed by the community police are the most searched ones. Maybe there should be a way to collect experiences about compatibility questions like this one to avoid such closings.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine for me as we'll as my 4 team members. Go for it.